# Angular how to pull the changes in a request changes of a git library?

Tags: angular

I am working on Angular 6. I am using a library like `crop` or amplify of `aws` etc. There are few useful changes which are in the library files like in its main component its module etc. 
I am not getting a way how to apply these changes in my project. 
Folder structure of the `node_modules/aws-amplify-angular/src/dist/`

Some said pull the fork and branch of the PR and merge in your local fork.
But could not understand.

Answer (score 0):

first check the status

```
git status
```

if found then

```
git add .
```

then

```
git commit -m "comment you want to type"
```

then take a pull

```
git pull
```

then push your code

```
git push -u origin branch_name
```